# Can't come back to initial page ViewController inside UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have `UIPageViewController`. Inside every page I have image view which is zoomable. Each time I zoom the image and go to next page I want my image not zoomed  when I  back to previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `viewWillAppear()` get called inside your `PageViewController` class? If so, you can implement the method there and reset your image zoom.

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    // Reset image zoom level here
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a function on your `PageViewController` and call it from your delegate method, however you'd need to call it in both the `viewControllerBefore` and `viewControllerAfter` methods so implementing `viewWillAppear` would be preferable.

Comment: The viewWillAppear() doesn't get called inside my PageViewController class, but I'll try your suggestion.thanks

Comment: Solved the  problem by adding  scrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: false) to my PageViewController  viewDidDisappear